# Regressing latent variables on observed variable using `sem` package in R

Tags: r, structural-equation-modeling

I'm having difficulty with some syntax in R using the `sem` package.  I'm trying to do the following:

1. Create four latent variables with three (attitudinal) indicators
   each
2. Regress these latent variables on an observed (behavioral)
       variable
3. Compare this to a model where I regress four latent variables with three indicators each on a higher-order latent variable

Using the `sem` package in R, my code for doing steps 1-2 is:

```
mydata.cov<-cov(mydata)
model.mydata <- specify.model() 
F1 ->  X1, lam1, NA
F1 ->  X2, lam2, NA 
F1 ->  X3, lam3, NA
F2 ->  X4, lam4, NA 
F2 ->  X5, lam5, NA
F2 ->  X6, lam6, NA
F3 ->  X7, lam7, NA
F3 ->  X8, lam8, NA
F3 ->  X9, lam9, NA 
F4 ->  X10, lam10, NA 
F4 ->  X11, lam11, NA
F4 ->  X12, lam12, NA
behav -> F1, lam13, NA
behav -> F2, lam14, NA
behav -> F3, lam15, NA
behav -> F4, lam16, NA
X1 <-> X1, e1,   NA 
X2 <-> X2, e2,   NA 
X3 <-> X3, e3,   NA 
X4 <-> X4, e4,   NA 
X5 <-> X5, e5,   NA 
X6 <-> X6, e6,   NA 
X7 <-> X7, e7,   NA 
X8 <-> X8, e8,   NA 
X9 <-> X9, e9,   NA 
X10 <-> X10, e10,   NA 
X11 <-> X11, e11,   NA 
X12 <-> X12, e12,   NA 
F1 <-> F1, e13, NA 
F2 <-> F2, e14, NA 
F3 <-> F3, e15, NA 
F4 <-> F4, e16,  NA 
behav <-> behav, NA, 1
```

Presumably, the second model would be similar code:

```
model2.mydata <- specify.model() 
F1 ->  X1, lam1, NA
F1 ->  X2, lam2, NA 
F1 ->  X3, lam3, NA
F2 ->  X4, lam4, NA 
F2 ->  X5, lam5, NA
F2 ->  X6, lam6, NA
F3 ->  X7, lam7, NA
F3 ->  X8, lam8, NA
F3 ->  X9, lam9, NA 
F4 ->  X10, lam10, NA 
F4 ->  X11, lam11, NA
F4 ->  X12, lam12, NA
F5 -> F1, lam13, NA
F5 -> F2, lam14, NA
F5 -> F3, lam15, NA
F5 -> F4, lam16, NA
X1 <-> X1, e1,   NA 
X2 <-> X2, e2,   NA 
X3 <-> X3, e3,   NA 
X4 <-> X4, e4,   NA 
X5 <-> X5, e5,   NA 
X6 <-> X6, e6,   NA 
X7 <-> X7, e7,   NA 
X8 <-> X8, e8,   NA 
X9 <-> X9, e9,   NA 
X10 <-> X10, e10,   NA 
X11 <-> X11, e11,   NA 
X12 <-> X12, e12,   NA 
F1 <-> F1, e13, NA 
F2 <-> F2, e14, NA 
F3 <-> F3, e15, NA 
F4 <-> F4, e16,  NA 
F5 <-> F5, NA, 1

model.sem2 <- sem(model2.mydata, mydata.cov, nrow(labor_coef))
# print results (fit indices, parameters, hypothesis tests) 
summary(model2.sem)
stdCoef(model2.sem)
```

Unfortunately, neither syntax appears to work.  Both models should be identified, and R just gives me a generic error message when I run the summary command:

Updated: Now, the model will run, but summary returns the following: `Error in summary.objectiveML(data.sem) : coefficient covariances cannot be computed`.

Thoughts?

Comment: what are the error messages? one issue , though prob a typo - behav goes onto F1 three times & same for F5. You may find it easier to define model with cfa: eg  cfa.mod <- cfa()
1: F1: x1 , x2 , x2

Comment: Thanks for catching the typo! (I changed my variable names for clarity).  The error message says: Error in classifyVariables(model) : incorrectly specified model

Comment: Updated:  Now, the model will run, but summary returns the following: `Error in summary.objectiveML(data.sem) : 
  coefficient covariances cannot be computed`

Comment: model is probably under-identified. Try setting factor variances to one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry i don't use specify model so can't spot the error (although perhaps set variances of factors to 1). I think `cfa` command might be a bit easier for specification. A wee example below:

```
library(MASS)    
library(sem)

# Create data
sigma <- matrix(c(1.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.3,
                  0.2, 1.0, 0.4, 0.5, 0.2, 0.6,
                  0.4, 0.4, 1.0, 0.3, 0.2, 0.6,
                  0.5, 0.5, 0.3, 1.0, 0.7, 0.2, 
                  0.6, 0.2, 0.2, 0.7, 1.0, 0.4, 
                  0.3, 0.6, 0.6, 0.2, 0.4, 1.0), 
                  nrow=6, byrow=T)    

df <- data.frame(mvrnorm(200 , c(10,15,20,25,30,35) , sigma))    
names(df) <- paste("X",1:6,sep="")    
df$age <- rnorm(100,40,15)

my.cor <- cor(df)

# Specify model
cfa.mod <- cfa(reference.indicators=FALSE, covs=NULL)    
F1: X1,X2,X3    
F2: X4,X5,X6    
age: F1,F2

# Look at model parameters
cfa.mod

# estimate model
cfa.sem <- sem(cfa.mod, S=my.cor, N=200) 
summary(cfa.sem)
```

Comment: Wow. That is SO MUCH EASIER. From the bottom of the heart of a crazed dissertating doctoral candidate...THANK YOU!

Comment: Nice example @user20650.  I will put that in my back pocket!